# C# Linq set merged lists as datasource

Tags: c#, list, linq, model

I'm currently merging to lists will be the datasource of a gridview. This is my code:

```
            // Get models
            var products = await API.Zelkon.Products.GetAll();
            var productsCurrencies = await API.Zelkon.CurrenciesBackend.Get();

            // Merge lists
            var results = products.Item1.Zip(productsCurrencies.Item1, (x, y) => new Tuple<Models.Products, Models.Zelkon.CurrenciesBackend>(x, y));

            // Create datasource
            var datasource = results.Select(r => new { r.Item2.price, r.Item2.setup_fee, r.Item1.product_number });

            GridProducts.DataSource = datasource;
            //  GridProducts.VisibleColumns("name");
            UI.CustomizeGridDefault(GridProducts);
```

My problem is that the value of `r.Item2.setup_fee` is always the value of the first row. I have checked the collection and the data is correct there.

Am I doing something wrong?

Below are the structures:

```
 class CurrenciesBackend
    {
        public string currency_name { get; set; }
        public string currency_code { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public double recommended_price { get; set; }
        public double setup_fee { get; set; }
        public int product_number { get; set; }
    }

class Products
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string invoice_layout { get; set; }
        public string layout_number { get; set; }
        public string payment_terms_name { get; set; }
        public string payment_terms_number { get; set; }
        public DateTime creation_date { get; set; }
        public int enabled { get; set; }
        public int is_subscription { get; set; }
        public int is_delivery_required { get; set; }
        public int allow_discount { get; set; }
        public int allow_trial { get; set; }
        public int max_discount { get; set; }
        public int max_discount_duration { get; set; }
        public int vat_percentage { get; set; }
        public int trial_period { get; set; }
        public int binding_period { get; set; }
        public int days_of_credit { get; set; }
        public int unit { get; set; }
        public string allowed_country_codes { get; set; }
        public int product_number { get; set; }
        public int authorize_invoice { get; set; }

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post some sample data so we can see what the structure is like? Most importantly `products.Item1` and `productsCurrencies.Item1`

Comment: @DekuDesu I have updated the question with the models

Comment: Your models have no property or field named `Item1` so what is `products.Item1`?

Comment: By the way, @NicklasChristensen, any reason to use the reference-type `Tuple` instead of the intrinsically supported `(x, y)`?

Comment: @NetMage, I can only assume that the API is returning a `Tuple`

Comment: @Rodrigo Rodrigues can you please show me an example of this?

Comment: Can you show the signatures of `API.Zelkon.Products.GetAll()` and `API.Zelkon.CurrenciesBackend.Get()`?